# REST web-services in Java using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

What I want to do is to use the 3M Healthcare Data Dictionary Access's web service API to translate a medical term (i.e. Aortic Aneurysm) in one medical coding language to another using the 3M HDD to map and match the two different languages.

I am very new to REST and Jersey and so far, I have managed to print "Hello World" on a Tomcat server using NetBeans.

It sounds pretty simple but I just need a little push to get a foot in the door.

---

Here are some things I've been struggling with from the getgo: (added another t to http because I don't have access)

htttp://host:port/api/cts/vb/getSupportedCodeSystems <-- This works and returns an XML with the supported code systems on a browser

htttp://host:port/api/cts/vb/lookupDesignations <-- This doesn't work because this one needs 2 parameters (a codeSystem_ID which is the code for a specific coding language and a Concept Code which is the code for a specific concept i.e. AANS for Aortic Aneurysm)

How am I supposed to integrate this into my Java code using REST and Jersey?

And how should I insert parameters for the method lookupDesignations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at any Jersey(-ish) example apps for how to make a request with parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it should work for you:

```
@Path("/lookupDesignations") // or you complete path
@GET
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getLookupDesignation(@QueryParam("codeSystemUid") String codeSystemUid, @QueryParam("conceptCode") String conceptCode) {
     // now you have codeSystemUid and conceptCode as String
     // create you entity or list for you entity to return as XML
     return Response.ok().entity(yourEntity).build();
}
```

You can use the [Rest Console for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) to simulate REST operations to your service.

example: .../lookupDesignations?codeSystemUid=111&conceptCode=java

You also com retrieve the variables in you URL path, like:

```
@Path("/lookupDesignations/{codeSystemUid}/{conceptCode}") // or you complete path
@GET
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getLookupDesignation(@PathParam("codeSystemUid") String codeSystemUid, @PathParam("conceptCode") String conceptCode) {
     // now you have codeSystemUid and conceptCode as String
     // create you entity or list for you entity to return as XML
     return Response.ok().entity(yourEntity).build();
}
```

In this example, you can call the URL: .../lookupDesignations/111/java

I hope that will be useful for you.

If I've misunderstood your question, please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for your input Deividi. Does this mean htttp://localhost:port/api/cts/vb/lookupDesignations/2.16.840.1.113883.3.232.99.5/AANS should work on my browser? For instance, let's say 2.16.840.1.113883.3.232.99.5 is the codeSystem_Id and AANS is the conceptCode for representing the medical term "Aortic Aneurysm".

Comment: Yes, it will work. With this URL, I think that should be more "prettier" to use codeSystemUid as last parameter. But the result will be the same.

Comment: How come it doesn't work for me? It says "Requested Resource Not Found
Sorry, we did not find the resource you were looking for."

Comment: This error happens because you make an http call to some URL that is not mapped in your application. Did you double checked the Jersey's web.xml configuration and you @Path annotation in your class/method?
Can you update your question and put your code for I take a look?